# WPF Question about displaying the image for Splash Screen

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, splash-screen

I have an image in my project.

In Solution Explorer, I've created a folder called "Resources" and I've added a single image in to that folder.

I want to set the image to the file in that folder. Here's my C# code

```
BitmapImage splashScreenImageSource = new BitmapImage();
splashScreenImageSource.BeginInit();
splashScreenImageSource.UriSource = new Uri("world_splash.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
splashScreenImageSource.EndInit();            
splashScreenImage.Source = splashScreenImageSource;
```

When I run, nothing happens.

Here's my XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="Bail.SplashScreen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="256" Width="456" Background="#00005555" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
    <Grid Width="Auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>        
        <Image x:Name="splashScreenImage" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Row="0" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thank you for all your help.
Here is App.xaml if you needed to see

```
<Application x:Class="Bail.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="SplashScreen.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to specify the subdirectory in the image path. You said it's in "Resources". So try using:

```
splashScreenImageSource.UriSource = new Uri("Resources/world_splash.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
```

**Edit**: You have to set the file type to resource for this to work. If you want to have it as a file in the file system (instead of embedded in your assembly) you have to use a pack uri, like:

```
splashScreenImageSource.UriSource = new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/world_splash.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
```

In this case make sure the "Copy to output directory" option of the file is set.

Also consider doing the initalization directly from XAML. It looks cleaner and requires less code:

```
<Image x:Name="splashScreenImage" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Row="0" Source="Resources/world_splash.jpg" />
```

Comment: I want to include the resources with my application. When I distribute it, I can't be sure if it will be available on the filesystem.